# Changing ordinal character data to numeric data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with letter grades: A, B, C, D and None.  I'd like to turn this into numeric data where A = 1, B = 2, etc.

I can think of a few ways I might go about this, but I want to know if there is an idiomatic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can skip the `'None':np.nan` part, as `conv_dict.get` returns `None` for value not in keys and `None` gets converted to `np.nan`. That, however, may or may not of the best maintainability.

```
In [49]:

df=pd.DataFrame({'data':['A','B','C','D','None']})
conv_dict={'A':1.,'B':2.,'C':3.,'D':4.,'None':np.nan}
df['data_c']=df.data.apply(conv_dict.get)
In [51]:

print df
   data  data_c
0     A       1
1     B       2
2     C       3
3     D       4
4  None     NaN
```